# Pass file urls dynamically in href

Tags: javascript, php, json

We have two json files , namely `shirt.json`, `phone.json`.

Both json files have different content.

We are displaying two links in page as below :

```
<a href = "http://1.1.1.1/folder1/editor.php?page=shirt">Shirt</a>

<a href = "http://1.1.1.1/folder1/editor.php?page=phone">Phone</a>
```

So that when clicking Shirt, it will fetch the `shirt.json` contents & same for `phone.json`.

I am using below code in `Editor.php`:

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>.json', function(data)
```

I kept json files shirt.json or phone.json in below folder :

> http:// 1.1.1.1/folder1/

**Requirement update**  :

suppose if we keep editor.php file one path : `http://1.1.1.1/folder1/`, json files in another path , say : `http://4.4.4.4/folder4/` , then how to pass those json file urls ?

Comment: So the full URL would be `http:// 4.4.4.4/folder4/shirt.json`, and your script automatically appends `.json` to the end of whatever value you pass already – can you not figure out what the “rest” of the full URL minus that suffix would be …?

Comment: (This has multiple security issues btw., cross site scripting and path traversal attacks are the first two that come to mind immediately.)

Comment: @misorude thanks for comment, but you misunderstood what i required, i keep  editor.php file & json files in different paths. in that case instead of `<?php echo $_GET['page'];` what i need to use to pass urls....

Comment: _“but you misunderstood what i required”_ - how? Rather looks to me like you still don’t see the answer, when it gets all but spelled out for you already. You want the end result of “x with `.json` put at the end” to be `http://4.4.4.4/folder4/shirt.json`, right? Well then what should x be in that case?

Comment: `$.getJSON('<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>.json', function(data)` this part won't work because the single quotes need to be escaped or double quotes/backticks should be used.

Comment: @misorude right now i have `http://1.1.1.1/folder1/editor.php?page=shirt` , here i keep shirt.json file in path : `http://1.1.1.1/folder1/` , if i use `http://4.4.4.4/folder4/shirt.json`, then it will work only if editor.php file is present in same folder as : `http://4.4.4.4/folder4/`, but editor.php file will be available only at one place here : `http://1.1.1.1/folder1/`

Comment: @EsliS Thanks for suggestion, but its working fine [in our website](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/landing)

Comment: @vickeycolors Oh yeah of course cause the PHP get's executed before it's parsed into the Javascript. Just looks a bit silly

Comment: First of all, please properly differentiate between (just) a different “folder” in a URL path, or a completely different host name / IP address. These are two significantly different things. What _doesn’t_ work then, with your editor? If this is not a JSONP request, then of course you need to have the endpoint you are making the request _to_ CORS-enabled, because you would be making an AJAX request to a different origin. Is that the case …?

Comment: @vickeycolors working XSS example. `alert` could be anything really. Just copy paste the the URL + js into your browser. Perhaps someone would even be able to optimise it so that the image would display. I ain't exactly a security expert I just like to mess around  


`http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/editor.php?page=phone.json', function(data) { alert("test"); }); function test(a) {} test(function test2(data) //`

Comment: @misorude right now i am passing json file name & getting solution. now  i need solution through url, i need to pass url. it may be in same ip or different ip. as you said, there is some CORS related things to make it work in different ip, can you please help me to make it work in same ip, assume `editor.php` file is in :  `http://1.1.1.1/folder1` & json files are in `http://1.1.1.1/folder2` , now what changes i need instead of this code : `$.getJSON('<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>.json', function(data)` ?

Comment: @EsliS sorry , i am not getting , what i need is assume `editor.php` file is in :  `http://1.1.1.1/folder1` & json files are in `http://1.1.1.1/folder2` , now what changes i need instead of this code : `$.getJSON('<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>.json', function(data)` ?

Comment: You could do `$.getJSON("http://1.1.1.1/folder2/<?php echo $_POST['page']; ?>.json", function(data) ...`, but I believe Magento has a different way of handling POST/GET parameters, and as I said in my last comment, this is really REALLY REALLY vulnerable to XSS attacks. It'd be better for you to use ENUMs or something like that

Comment: Maybe you should go and read up on the basics of how relative URLs work a bit … If you are “in” `http://1.1.1.1/folder1/` and want to refer to `http://1.1.1.1/folder2/shirt.json`, then you can of course simply do that by using `../folder2/shirt.json`. So what parameter value you’d need to pass then, if the `.json` part gets appended automatically, should be pretty obvious? You can of course pass the full absolute URL as well - what part of `http://1.1.1.1/folder2/shirt.json` needs to get left of, if `.json` gets appended automatically - also pretty clear, no?

Comment: @Eslis what if I have json files in both folder1 and folder2, please give me dynamic solution....

Comment: @Eslis what if I have json files in both folder1 and folder2, please give me dynamic solution.... Also it's pure php, we are not using Magento.....

Comment: @vickeycolors Your favicon is the Magento logo that's why I thought you guys used it.

Anyways, if you guys don't care about security anyways, just do `$.getJSON("http://1.1.1.1/<?php $_POST['page']; ?>.json", function(data) ...` with the page parameter being `folder1/shirt`. Don't say I didn't warn you about XSS and other security issues tho

Comment: @Eslis thanks, I will try this once I will be in front of keyboard, what to do if json files are in different ip , like 4.4.4.4/folder4

Comment: Sure why not make the page parameter contain the entire url ‍♀️ Like I said before, it'd be safer for you to use ENUMs or some other constant

Comment: @Eslis , sure I will use whatever you suggest, I have no idea about those enums.... What all I need is working solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this, adapt to your needs. Your URL would be: http://1.1.1.1/folder1/editor.php?page=SHIRT

Create an abstract class in a seperate file. This will kind of work like an enum.

```
<?php

abstract class Pages {

    public const SHIRT = "http://1.1.1.1/folder1/shirt.json";
    public const PHONE = "http://1.1.1.1/folder2/phone.json";

}
```

Then, right above the JS you will build in a check to see if the URL actually exists. Only if the URL is valid, you will get the JSON.

```
//convert the string to upper, just in case the parameter is shirt instead of SHIRT
<?php $page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? strtoupper($_GET['page']) : ""); ?>

//if the constant doesn't exist
<?php if(defined("Pages::{$page}")): ?>
   //the page parameter is valid
   $.getJSON(<?php echo constant("Pages::{$page}"); ?>, (data) => {
      //do stuff
   });

<?php else: ?>
   //the page parameter is malformed
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i updated your code = > [Abstract.php](https://pastebin.com/ydaCVAy7) , [editor.php](https://pastebin.com/PVuAcg6P) , [url page](https://pastebin.com/fiG1pAE8) , please let me know do i need to do any other changes to access url ?

Comment: You could remove the `<?php else: ?>` line if you don't need it. Aside from that I think it should work now.

EDIT: You should also require the abstract.php file in your editor.php file

Comment: Thanks, but when i click on [links in this page](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/landing) , its not fetching images from json files.... i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` for some reason.....

Comment: You messed up some syntaxing when integrating my code. Here's an [updated version](https://pastebin.com/mmNqbMSY) that should work imo

Comment: sorry for that, i updated your code, please check [links on those pages](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/landing).....

Comment: Just noticed I made a small mistake, line 304 `<?php endif; ?>` should be moved up until it's above line 301 `});`.
Seems like it's a PHP error. Maybe Abstract.php is located elsewhere? What do the server logs say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197155/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-eslis).